# Dubious 'You have reached your question limit' ban leads to counterproductive user behavior

Tags: discussion

My last two questions were not well accepted, and now I have this ban. But I am trying to make a living out of video editing among other things, so getting my questions answered on time is above any other consideration. Luckily I have no questions for the moment, but if I need something, you bet I will be tempted to do one of the following things (and I bet I am not the first user to think about it)

- Registering under another name/address and make my question.
- Simply editing one of my older questions, for which I don'g give a s**t any more, and rewriting it with the new question.

Both of them equally counterproductive for the site. Having duplicate profiles / erasing old contents that might be interesting. I have not done any of them for the moment, er, this time, but... I wonder who was the genius that invented this rule. Kudos for him or her. Yes, this is irony. Please change that.

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not really a personal help desk, but a repository of high-quality Q&A, and everyone is just a volunteer. So, no one is under obligation to solve your problem within the time constraint. Also, doing any of those could make your account suspended for abusing this platform. Also, [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).

Answer (score 7):

Yeah both of your suggestions are exactly what **not** to do.

Editing an old question into something completely different just does not make sense, and thus is not allowed.

Say you asked about the compositor, got some comments maybe even an answer, but now you need to ask about the VSE. After the editing the compositor question (SE would call that vandalism) none of the comments or answers make any sense anymore.

---

The more commonly tried loophole is simply to make another account and try again. (PS Did you make a [new account](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/69293/pegostes) in the last few days?)

*If* that works, because "bans are at a lower level then accounts" you still will get your accounts suspended. Creating a new account to circumvent a question ban is definitely a no-no.

With what **not** to do out of the way, start by editing your existing questions. (The deleted questions are counting too.) Make then clear, specific, and something that is answerable.

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/99182/2217) is a good one (also happened to be your only positively voted one, voting really does tell you something of the quality...)

[This one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/131190/2217) is not a real question. It is more of a rant with a question mark. We as users have no way of commenting on the distribution of developer's time. "Questions" like this will *always* be DVed and closed.

[Your newest](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/131982/5) question would be fine with a bit of editing to make it clearer and direct to the point (don't forget the title). I already edited that one for you to give you an idea what I mean.

PS when someone tries to help, gives you advice whether about one of your posts, or in a comment. Don't get an attitude and sarcastically retort. Not only is that counter productive, but it gives other users (like me) a disdain to even try to help you. I was *very* close to not writing this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the good will and the editing. However I think you don't get the purpose of this question (this one, in meta). Not ranting, not attacking, but genuinely pointing out what I consider a counterproductive rule. I appreciate the help, but not the ban, and I am pointing out at how counterproductive it can be. And I know you can identify if I opened another account, but when people really want to circumvent that, they will do it anyway. Just opening the account from the mobile phone network will have a different IP and OS... Again, thanks, but consider my point: that rule is no good.

Comment: @Mephisto I get where you are coming from. But think about it from the other side. The reason the question or answer ban is in place is to *try* to keep some measure of quality on the SE sites. In SE's eye's if you can not make posts that are good, then they don't really want you here. (that is probably over stating it.) They need *something* to keep quality standers. This is what we have, if you have an alternative then the [meta.se] is the place to suggest it. (be forewarned though, the meta is not a friendly place.)

Comment: Unluckily, those *somethings* designed to keep quality standards, quite often lead to mediocrity. I cannot forget what happened in 2013 with Physics SE. It was brillant. On a daily basis you would have there answers, questions, comments and general interaction of a Nobel Prize, a former Cambridge Professor, research-level scholars and university lecturers, and even some crazy independent maverick genius. But SE started banning and censoring and imposing PC, and in a few weeks all brilliant people went away and since then it is a crappy repository of elementary school questions.